# If $f^{-1}[\cap_{i\in i}B_i]\subseteq f^{-1}[B_i]\Rightarrow f^{-1}[\cap_{i\in i}B_i]\subseteq \cap_{i\in I}f^{-1}[B_i]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I may be missing something trivial, I manage to prove that 
for all $i\in I$ we get $$f^{-1}[\cap_{i \in I}B_i]\subseteq f^{-1}[B_i]$$

Now, why can I take the intersection and say that:

$$f^{-1}[\cap_{i \in I}B_i]\subseteq \cap_{i\in I}f^{-1}[B_i]$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a set $S$ and a family of sets $\{S_\lambda\,|\,\lambda\in\Lambda\}$, then, by definition of intersection, asserting that $S\subset\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}S_\lambda$ is the same thing as assertiong that $(\forall\lambda\in\Lambda):S\subset S_\lambda$.

Therefore, since,$$(\forall i\in I):f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i\right)\subset f^{-1}(B_i),$$it follows that$$f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i\right)\subset\bigcap_{i\in I}f^{-1}(B_i).$$

Comment: You clear and precise explation did the trick, thanks!

Comment: @newhere I'm glad I could help.